# How does MISRA C++ Code Compliance ensure Functional safety and Quality?

Tags: c++, coding-style, misra, software-quality, autosar

Could Anyone explain to me how MISRA C++(2008) is in incompliance with functional safety(ISO 26262), If it is really in compliance with which rules contribute to functional safety?
Is there a document or proof stating that MISRA C++ is in Compliance with ISO26262 and AUTOSAR?
For quality assurance, on following MISRA C++ coding standard what assurance does it give to software development code

Comment: "If I blindly follow this coding standard, will I be compliant?" probably not. Adopting a coding standard such as MISRA is will help you achieve compliance by keeping you away from the more explody bits of the language. But it is a small part of that, in the end it is your code that has to comply with the requirements, coding standard or not.

Comment: One of the biggest problems we face is QA Managers (or similar) demanding *100% MISRA compliance with no deviations* - which is so irritating when we (in MISRA) have defined a deviation process for when it is required!  Blind box-ticking is flawed!

Comment: @Andrew What I recommend when implementing MISRA-C is rather to implement a company standard and demand 100% compliance to that internal standard. This way you ban individual deviations but allow company-wide deviations as part of the coding standard document. Then configure MISRA-C checkers accordingly, removing checks for company-wide deviations only. It works very well in my experience, because then you force a discussion and review by others whenever someone comes up with an idea to deviate. I wouldn't trust individual programmers to do such unless they are very experienced.

Comment: Yup... fully agree @Lundin.  What is important is where you deviate from the Rules, you know why and what the consequences are... and what additional remedial action to take (eg enhanced testing)

Comment: And this is especially true in cases where a deviation is required, or even specified in a Permit!

Comment: I don't have access to these standards currently, but generally ISO 26262 lists "Use of language subsets" as something highly recommended for all ASIL levels. Generally these standards also have a list of suitable programming languages. Traditionally, only C with safe subset (MISRA-C etc) or Ada with safe subset (SPARK Ada etc) where considered suitable for safety-critical systems. I don't know if this has been changed by lobbyists over the years, but I doubt that engineers or experts would ever approve of C++. I'd dismiss all such claims of suitability as a scam to sell tools.

Comment: C++ beyond C++11 has gone completely haywire too, which doesn't exactly improve the situation.

Comment: 100% MISRA compliance without deviations? There are processes and methods/guildelines you folllow, and deviations are documented and reviewed and other countermeasures applied. Processes can (at least in the past) be tailored. Certain FuSa meaures are sometimes just bullshit, the system might be robust, going into "safe silent state", but actually, it's not available. I sometimes wonder, where/when the ISO26262 and FuSa actually took the common sense away. Probably when there were too many "managers" and only one rower left.

Comment: While this question is related to the overall software development lifecycle, it is not a practical programming problem within the scope of Stack Overflow as established by the [help].

Answer (score 2):

As MISRA C and MISRA C++ themselves state, they require development to be part of a documented software development lifecycle - they will not (themselves) guarantee your system works.

MISRA C/C++ meet many of the requirements of ISO26262... but it's rather a lengthy topic, and StackOverflow is not an ideal place to give a full answer, as it's very context dependant.

As someone with a foot in both camps (see profile) I've done several presentations on *MISRA C in an ISO 26262 context* (and the same applies to MISRA C++). For example:

https://www.slideshare.net/AdaCore/misra-c-in-an-iso-26262-context

(apologies in advance for the corporate guff at the start!)

But since you have also mentioned AUTOSAR Adaptive - this REQUIRES compliance with MISRA C++

https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf

> **5.1.1 Rule classification according to compatibility with MISRA** 
> The rules in this document are defined as a “delta” to MISRA C++:2008

Comment: Do you know if ISO 26262 have expanded the list of suitable programming languages to include "C++ with subset"? The "parent" standard IEC 61508 has not done this AFAIK.

Comment: 61508 is under revision at the moment... I'm not involved, and have no visibility as to whether C++ gets a mention.  26262:18 doesn't explicitly mention C++ which is perhaps a surprise given that AUTOSAR adaptive is C++ but then again, it doesn't mandate any specific language... 26262-6 para 5.4 applies.

Comment: What I was thinking of is the table of suitable languages equivalent to IEC 61508-7 Table C.1. Only languages with a safe subset are "highly recommended" for the higher SIL levels. My version of IEC 61508-7:2000 does not include C++ at all.

Comment: In 2000 (which pre-dates MISRA C++) C++ was deemed not-suitable... it was with the advent of JSF-AV Coding Standards in 2005 (based on MISRA C, as a stepping stone towards and involving some of the people behind MISRA C++) that brought it into the safety-critical mainstream...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But nowhere there is a mention that MISRA C++ is in compliance with Functional safety ISO26262, MISRA claims to be a safe, secure and reliable standard for automotive. My question is how does it achieve this?Yes the rules are a subset of C++ programming language but how can it claim to be safe ?Is it taking ISO26262 or any safety standard into consideration

Comment: As with my reply to Lundin, choice of Language is up to the developer - there is no list of OK or not OK languages (see Part 6 clause 5.4).  MISRA C/C++ helps meet many of the requirements of 26262 - in particular, it stops you using the unsafe and incompletely-defined features of the language, and stops you doing silly things.  If you've looked at my presentation, it has my email address in it - I'm happy to discuss details off line :-)

Comment: @VaishnaviS My personal opinion is that C++ is a wildly dangerous language and should not be allowed to come near any safety-critical project. If you were to create a safe subset of C++, you have to ban some 90% of the language. If it isn't listed by ISO 26262 then that makes perfect sense. Using C is already bad enough, but at least all flaws of C are well-known.

Comment: Yes @Lundin i agree C++ is quite dangerous but unfortunately all Adaptive autosar projects need C++ coding language (This is the standard required by customer) and I am not quite sure if MISRA C++ is the ideal coding standard to convince my quality assurance team that my code is complaint with ISO26262 also.In misra.org discussion pages I saw discussion mentioning that The newest version of MISRA C++ will take autosar standards into consideration ,Is this true? does MISRA C++ 2008 also do the same

Comment: AUTOSAR Adaptive uses MISRA C++ as its basis, with some extra Rules for C++14/17 (which the forthcoming MISRA C++ will include)...

Comment: @Lundin: There are about a million Dutch citizens with dry feet thanks to the automated surge barrier near Rotterdam. And that was automated because the risk assessment showed that C++ was the safest solution, exceeding even human judgement. Automotive is a much more benign field; risks are limited to a handful of people per incident.

Comment: Answer updated to reference AUTOSAR Adaptive spec... and the link to MISRA C++

Comment: @MSalters Oh it _is_ perfectly possible to develop safe C++ programs. It just takes a whole lot more skill and effort, and you'll have to write several books about which C++ features that are banned and unsuitable. Like writing the book about how all poorly-defined behavior in C++ is covered and handled by the project.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks that was helpful,I am assuming MISRA would do this in the new release for C++ Coding standard?

Comment: @VaishnaviS Yes... the next MISRA C++:202x will incorporate AUTOSAR and C++ upto C++17

Answer (score -2):

> How does MISRA C++ Code Compliance ensure Functional safety and Quality?

I tend to think it does not *ensure* safety or software quality. It does *contribute* to it (among other *more important* factors, including project management, work experience of developers, efforts allocated to [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) ....).

It is a human process. It could fail. It is helpful.

You could use software static or dynamic analysis tools (like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), [Fluctuat](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Sylvie.Putot/fluctuat.html), [AbsInt](https://www.absint.com/), [Astrée](https://www.astree-software.fr/en/), [Cadna](http://cadna.lip6.fr/), [Papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_(software)), [CompCert](https://compcert.org/), or use a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -fanalyzer` and perhaps even write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) etc...) but at the end of the day you need human cooperation and [code reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review).

See also projects like [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/), [VESSEDIA](https://vessedia.eu/) (or [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/)).

Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Remember that software issues (but not only) have been involved in [Boeing 737 MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX) crashes.

Notice that major C++ compilers (including [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)) are *not* MISRA C++ compliant. Some improved versions of them have been certified. And GCC and Clang are mostly coded in C++...

Some critical software (e.G. the software part of [Recovid](https://github.com/Recovid/Controller) - a COVID breathing machine - open hardware / open software in France) are AFAIK not MISRA C certified (but certified against other standards)

For example, the rule

> Rule M0-1-1 (required, implementation, automated)  A project shall not contain unreachable code.

is really hard to *prove* (just by inspection or automated analysis of the source code).

Comment: The 737MAX was *not* a software issue... it was a flawed system design problem, in which the software did exactly what it was specified to do in the circumstances.  Unfortunately the system spec was wrong, and sensors not appropriate for the level of flight-criticality :(

Comment: Yes, but who wrote that software? Who specified it? who managed its development?

Comment: Nothing in this answer has anything to do with MISRA-C++ or ISO 26262 so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Frama-C (developed by colleagues) is related to MISRA-C

Comment: FRAMA is *similar* to MISRA C but is not related... perhaps there is a conversation to be had there?!

Comment: My question is for quality assurance, After my implementation phase to ensure my code is complaint(Safe and Secure) I need to  ensure that the coding standard is good enough to be delivered to the customer(Yes there are other part of the software development cycle like unit testing,functional testing etc.) but with respect to code would MISRA C++ suffice to ensure that my code is incomplaince with ISO26262 also?If so is there a documented proof stating this ?

Comment: Define "proof" (mathematical one?). Define quality assurance (ISO9001?) Define "delivery" (can you show source code to your customer)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Safety standards like ISO 26262 define what the quality system must live up to. It's not enough to wave around some ISO 9001 certificate.

Comment: @Lindin: I know that. I was trained on both ISO 26262 and ISO 9001.

Comment: Well good, then perhaps your answer could mention which programming languages (with or without safe subset) that ISO 26262 lists as recommended?

Comment: No, because I am not sure to be authorized to tell that.

Comment: @Basile, Offcourse the source code will not be visible to the customer but during delivery every client demands of a code compliance check (Static code analysis).And hence I found MISRA C++.But since my system is a Safety system (Adaptive Autosar) is MISRA C++ the best choice?,Please Note MISRA C++ not C..

Comment: @VaishaviS: my strong opinion is that the source code should be shown to the customer. (I do know horror stories where it was not).

Comment: It doesn't violate any copyright to quote parts of a technical standard or just refer to a chapter as a source. Otherwise half of SO would be closed down by ISO already.

Comment: @Lundin and Basil,Yes But my question is still not answered :(,So is MISRA C++ recommended for safety critical systems (This is what is claims) If so how does it satisfy ISO26262?

Comment: You forgot an important thing: [common sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_sense). It matter more than ISO26262... Your question is a matter of opinion. Some software (e.g. the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/)...) are not ISO26262 but are quite robust in practice: example the [Recovid](https://github.com/Recovid/Controller) controller (software part of a COVID respirator machine)

Comment: Since your your *system is a Adaptive Autosar system* then, yes, MISRA C++ is required.  Read the AUTOSAR documentation... it REQUIRES MISRA C++ Compliance

Comment: @Basile The matter of common sense doesn't really matter to the quality assurance team sometimes ( No offense intended), When I say that my code is in compliance with MISRA C++ which ensure safety and security,They would ask how?

Comment: MISRA C++ is needed if your client pays for it (and then you need to charge more).

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure?I really couldnt find this statement saying Adaptive Autosar needs MISRA complaince

Comment: @VaishnaviS There's (expensive) programs that can be used for ISO 26262 requirements tracing. You can link each requirement to your own directives, tests and so on and thereby demonstrate compliance. In either case you need to write a tonne of documentation, but such tools may save you from some of that paperwork.

Comment: "A project shall not contain unreachable code" could be proven with dynamic analysis and that's how it would be done in the most critical systems. That is, you have to take the live program through all possible use-cases while recording the program counter. Then you simply compare the lines executed with the C source and/or machine code. It's not hard to prove at all, though it is cumbersome to integrate dynamic analysis tool with your project. Other ways are _formal methods_, but that's not something I've ever used personally.

Comment: Though static analysers and/or compilers do find the majority of "dead code" at compile-time, in my experience.

Comment: Anyways, the question "How does MISRA C++ Code Compliance ensure Functional safety and Quality?" can definitely be answered. Functional safety is a special snowflake kind of provable paperwork safety, that exists in a mathematical intersection with _actual safety_, which is what makes the product safe. That's where the common sense part kicks in. These functional safety standards contain a lot of good advise, but they also contain a lot of nonsense. In order to develop an _actually safe_ product, you have to use common sense to cherry pick the parts of functional safety that make sense.

Comment: @VaishnaviS It's not an answer... I'd write one if I had access to ISO 26262, which I currently don't.

Comment: Best, if that question would be closed and deleted. Then, all the dangerous nonesense in answers and comments would vanish. I rarely vote to close a question. But here I will. Not, because the question is bad, but too many comments are really unbelievable.